# Lazy loading open modals [Ionic 5]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic5

I have tried to lazy-load open a modal in Ionic 5. I have multiple modals to be opened in the same page, so I thought of doing a single function that will open the modal by their string name, given through parameter. It worked on Ionic 3 and also it's written on the ionic 5 documentation. See image below:

[image: The capability to open modals by string name]

Here's the code:

```
async presentModal(modalName: string) {
  const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
    component: modalName,
    componentProps: {
      'note': this.massageNote.content
    }
  });
  return await modal.present();
}
```

The function call:

```
presentModal('AssessmentSectionModalPage');
```

When calling the function, here's the error I get.

> Error: No component factory found for AssessmentSectionModalPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

I have also imported the 'AssessmentSectionModalPageModule' in my page's module, but still getting this. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you add it in imports of app.modupe or page.module?

Comment: Yes, already done that. Same error every time.

Comment: If you remove the componentprops will it work?

Comment: Tried various ways. Still doesn't work. :(

Comment: I think the way is wrong and i'll test it today and give you an answer, but did you try function or htmlelement? And as i said, will reply after some hours when i reach my computer

Answer (score 0):

Same for me, remove componentProps have no efect.